# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS issue after Magento2 install, possible Ubuntu virtual host issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, ubuntu

I installed Magento2 on Ubuntu 14.04 following [Magento's sets of instructions][1]:

After getting [SUCCESS]: Magento Installation Complete. the site should work, but getting **ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error.**

I suspect a misconfiguration of Virtual Hosts as there are a few sites on this server.

**nfcshop.ca.conf** file below from `sites-available` and is linked in `sites-enabled`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName nfcshop.ca
    ServerAlias nfcshop.ca
    ServerAdmin admin@nfcshop.ca
    DocumentRoot /var/www/magento
    Redirect permanent /  http://nfcshop.ca/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/shop-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/shop.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/magento/>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I put a `.htaccess` file in `var/www/magento`

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

service apache2 restart is [OK]

I tried different browsers and clearing cache and cookies to no avail.

All the other sites on the same server are still working. Not sure what I am missing. Thank you!

Comment: It maybe obvious but did you try removing  Redirect permanent line?

Comment: the obvious was correct, thank you! If you put it in the answer, I'll vote.

Comment: Glad it worked! I've added my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, removing the line

```
    Redirect permanent /  http://nfcshop.ca/
```

worked.

Answer (score 0):

I got the error `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` because I forgot to set the `PHP` version to `PHP7`.